# Correct usage of lftp mirror --older-than

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to use lftp to download all files from a remote ftp server to the local server in our multi-site enterprise that are older than a certain age and remove them from the remote server.

The command I'm trying is:

```
lftp -c "set ftp:list-options -a; set ftp:passive-mode false; open ftp://user:pass@host:port; cd '/path/'; mirror --older-than 30s --Remove-source-files --verbose"
```

The problem is I get the error: 30s: No such file or directory

Likewise with "--older-than now-5min"

Am I reading the man page wrong?

For the curious, here's why: I only want to grab the completed files from the remote server... I want "--older-than 30s" so it skips files that are still being written to.

Comment: If you question remains closed here, I'd recommend taking it over to linux.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 7):

it should be

```
--older-than=now-5minutes
```

from *man lftp*

> For options --newer-than and --older-than you can either specify a
>   file or time specification like that used by **at(1)** command, e.g. 
>   `now-7days' or`week ago'. If you specify a file, then modification
>   time of that file will be used.

from *man at*:

> You can also give times like now + count time-units, where the
>   time-units can be **minutes**, **hours**, **days**, or **weeks** and you can tell at
>   to run the job today by suffixing the time with today and to run the
>   job tomorrow by suffixing the time with tomorrow.